# Use FBO's position buffer and color buffer for rendering (post-rendering 3D warp)

Tags: opengl, rendering, fbo

I want to implement post-rendering 3D warp using position data and color data stored in a FBO. How to do it efficiently in modern OpenGL? By position data, they are camera-relative XYZ coordinates.

I have two FBOs, say fbo1 and fbo2. fbo1 is for data (position+color) input, and fbo2 is for data output (the results after post-rendering 3D warp). FBO setup code for both FBOs is as following:

```
void setupFBO( int width, int height )
{
    // Create and bind the FBO
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);

    // The depth buffer
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &fboDepthBuf);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, fboDepthBuf);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);

    // The color buffer
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &fboColorTex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboColorTex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    // The position buffer
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glGenTextures(1, &fboPosTex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboPosTex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    // Attach the images to the framebuffer
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, fboDepthBuf);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboColorTex, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboPosTex, 0);

    // Set the targets for the fragment output variables
    GLenum drawBuffers[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
    glDrawBuffers(2, drawBuffers);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

Assume we've data stored in fbo1, i.e. color data in fbo1.fboColorTex and position data in fbo1.fboPosTex, and we know the transformation (modelview) matrix needed for transforming the position data and also the projection matrix. How to obtain the transformed position and color data? One way to implement it could be like the following:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo2);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo1.fboColorTex);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo1.fboPosTex);
// set shader parameters for textures
// set modelview, projection matrices
// what to render here? A full-screen quad?
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

What do render? And what shaders should look like?

The other way I can think of is to use dynamic VBOs, but I'm not sure how to dynamically assign VBO's vertex and color data from textures (in fbo1)... The reason that I mention dynamic VBO is because fbo1's data can be changed but not frequently.

Comment: Reconstruct position from depth if you want to do this efficiently. You are requiring 96-bits to store the position, 64-bits for color and somewhere between 16- and 32-bit for the depth. That is potentially 192-bit (24 bytes) per-pixel. You can cut this in half if you eliminate the position buffer; you may have plenty of memory and think that this hardly matters, but the reason you want to cut it in half is actually to reduce memory bandwidth requirements.

Comment: Also, you might consider using `GL_R11F_G11F_B10F` for your color if you do not need an alpha channel. This will give you a floating-point color format capable of use for HDR but with half the memory footprint.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks for the comments! But I need code-level help now. After I succeed with this most simple-to-implement case (no need of reconstructing position from depth), I can try your suggestions. And for the color format, I'm using GL_RGBA16F for CUDA/GL interoperability.